# Should Old Testament Prophecies Concerning YHWH and His Messiah be collapsed into Yahweh?

Tags: prophecy, deuteronomy, messiah, tetragrammaton

> Blockquote 15 “**The LORD your God** will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brothers—it is to **him** you shall listen— 16 just as you desired of the LORD your God at Horeb on the day of the assembly, when you said, ‘Let me not hear again the voice of the LORD my God or see this great fire any more, lest I die.’ 17 And the Lord said to me, ‘They are right in what they have spoken. 18 I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brothers. And I will put my words in his mouth, and he shall speak to them all that I command him. (Dt 18:15–18, ESV).

In this prophetic utterance (v. 15), the word “LORD” (all caps in some English Bibles, Jehovah in some languages, etc.) is the exclusive, sacred name for God (YHWH). Verse 15 delineates between the sender YHWH (“the LORD your God”) and “him” (the prophet) as two distinct persons. In consistent fashion, verse 18 retains distinct pronouns: “I” applies to YHWH and “he” applies to the prophet.

When interpreting this prophecy in the New Testament should we collapse these two distinct persons (YHWH and the Messiah) into YHWH, or should we understood this prophecy as YHWH sending a Messiah who would not be YHWH? For similar prophetic passages that made a strong distinction between YHWH and the coming Messiah, please see Micah 5:4, Psalm 2:2,7, 45:7, 89:26, 110:1, Isaiah 42:1-3, 53:6, 61:1, and Jeremiah 30:9.

Comment: There are cases wherein YHWH and the Messiah are said to share the same name, and reputation, without being the same person (see Philippians 2:9-11). They are two distinct persons but possess the same thing i.e. divine name and divine honours. In this unity, they are defined by the church as one God in the qualitative sense (e.g. homoousios - of the same thing, substance/nature).

Comment: Persons cannot be 'collapsed' into one, either literally in reality or grammatically in word. I have no idea what is being suggested. This question needs some serious clarity and focus in my opinion. Nor can Old Testament wording be 'updated' retrospectively by virtue of further revelation in the New Testament. The Hebrew says what it says and should be honoured accordingly.

Comment: (-1) I am really struggling to understand how you've arrived at the term 'Messiah' in this passage, and so it feels more like this question is being imposed upon the text rather than arising' naturally from it. Usually it's challenging enough to prove passages are genuinely 'messianic' even when they have the term 'Messiah' literally written in them. I think now would be a good time to pull out a few commentaries and do some digging around the passage.

Comment: You seem to be asking this in the binary as if there are only two choices. There are really three options. It's not  either "we collapse these two distinct persons" OR "YHWH sends a Messiah who would not be YHWH" - There is also both/and available to us in which we do not "collapse" these two distinct persons into one, and we also understand the Messiah as YHWH. How we should interpret this is certainly a matter of debate, with division between Judaism, [Arians and triniterians/Athenasians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arian_controversy)

Answer (score 0):

There are several question wrapped up in one here so I will separate them somewhat.

**Pronouns:**

The antecedent of most of the pronouns are clear so let me make this explicit in Deut 18:15-20.  Recall that Moses is speaking a reporting a conversation between YHWH and Moses, which he is then reporting to the people.

> **15** The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me **[Moses]** from among your **[Israelite]** brothers. You **[Israelites]** must listen to him **[the prophet]**. **16** This is what you **[Israelites]** asked of the LORD your God at Horeb on the
> day of the assembly, when you **[Israelites]** said, “Let us not hear
> the voice of the LORD our God or see this great fire anymore, so that
> we will not die!”
>
> **17** Then the LORD said to me **[Moses]**, “They have spoken well. **18** I will raise up for them a prophet like you **[Moses]** from among their **[Israelite]** brothers. I **[YHWH]** will put My words
> in his **[the prophet's]** mouth, and he will tell them
> **[Israelites]** everything I command him. **19** And I will hold accountable anyone who does not listen to My words that the prophet
> speaks in My name. **20** But if any prophet dares to speak a message
> in My name that I have not commanded him to speak, or to speak in the
> name of other gods, that prophet must be put to death.”

OK, so this is a fairly simple prophecy about a further prophet like Moses.  There are at least three ways to understand this prophecy:

1. That God would call others to the prophetic office as He done with Moses - this occurred in people such as Deborah, Samuel, David, Solomon, Isaiah, Jeremiah, etc.  This understanding is strengthened by the general flow of the passage (V9-14) that contrasts false prophets and sorcerers with the true prophets.  Ps 105:15, Amos 3:7
2. On the basis of Acts 3:22, 23 another interpretation is that Jesus, Messiah, fulfilled this prophecy.  This is further confirmed by Jesus saying that He only speaks what He hears the Father say, John 14:10, etc.
3. The Holy Spirit  who only speaks what He hears John 16:13, 14.  [See Ellicott for further details.]

Barnes succinctly summarizes this (Deut 18:15):

> In fact, in the words before us, Moses gives promise both of a
> prophetic order, and of the Messiah in particular as its chief; of a
> line of prophets culminating in one eminent individual. And in
> proportion as we see in our Lord the characteristics of the prophet
> most perfectly exhibited, so must we regard the promise of Moses as in
> Him most completely accomplished.

Comment: how do you figure #3 if it is from the 'brothers'?

Comment: You are not addressing the clear distinction that Moses made between Yahweh and His prophet and how this should be interpreted in the New Testament.

Comment: @user48152 - good question - the NT quotes this passage, or alludes to it when speaking of the the HS as referenced above.

Comment: @JesusSaves - I do not see that that is a problem here.  All that says is that there is a distinction between the the Father and Jesus but that does not preclude Jesus being YHWH as taught in many other places.

Comment: To me, the voting for this answer (-3 and +2, at the present time) indicates theological preferences and not logical and dispassionate assessment of content.